# Correct usage of defer in Swift

Tags: swift

My code looks like this and it works great but I want to know if the way I used `defer` is correct.

```
func setupCamera() {
        var didSucceed = false
        defer {
            if !didSucceed {
                // Fail gracefully and show alert
            }
        }
        if let camera = getDevice(position: .back) {
            do {
                input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: camera)
                if(session.canAddInput(input)) {
                    session.addInput(input)
                    output.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecJPEG]
                    if(session.canAddOutput(output)) {
                        session.addOutput(output)
                        if let layer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session) {
                            layer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
                            layer.connection.videoOrientation = .portrait
                            layer.frame = cameraPreview.bounds
                            cameraPreview.layer.addSublayer(layer)
                            session.startRunning()
                            didSucceed = true
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
```

I know the fact that it should be used for deallocation of elements.

Comment: It's correct but completely unnecessary. It would be more readable if you just put the `if !didSucceed` to the end of the method - or split the central block to a separate method.

Comment: Also, try using `guard let ` for better readability. This will flatten the code

Comment: I will try those things, @MaximKosov can you show me how it will be done with `gaurd let`

Comment: This would be off topic. In general, you could just replace strings like `if let camera = getDevice(position: .back)` with something like `guard let camera = getDevice(position: .back) else { return; }`. The code would be exactly the same as before, but you will avoid nested `if`-s a.k.a 'pyramid of doom'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntactically, yes it is correct. But this is a wrong application of the intended use of `defer`.

It should not be used to fail gracefully like you are doing, because you are performing logic that does not have a "cleanup" scope but it is part of the logic flow of the function. (And how you would test that?)

The intended use of `defer` is to make sure you cleanup everything and to simplify readability. Performing that kind of logic inside `defer` defeats its intended use.